# htaccess redirect both https, www, and old page to new

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to do redirects from http to https, and just the domain to www. I also want some 301 redirects of old to new pages.

this is my current htaccess.

```
    #RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I've tried adding this (below) and other things but none of them do the redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /cat_cp.asp?cid=179 https://www.amep.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=179
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: So, you don't have `RewriteEngine On` uncommented anywhere in your htaccess file?

Comment: I've uncommented and added the "Redirect 301..." line from above and it doesn't redirect.

Comment: I added this "Redirect 301 /cat_cp.asp?cid=179 https://www.amep.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=179" after uncommenting #RewriteEngine On

Comment: You don't want the redirect line, that's going to conflict as it's not even part of the rewrite engine.

Comment: How do i do this? In other words, how do i add a redirect from an old page to a new one? I have about 1022 pages to redirect. I have those created, i just need to know how/where to enter them.

Comment: I expected that the code block under *this is my current htaccess* is what is your current htaccess. **WITHOUT** the redirect (either way, that's not even the right syntax for Redirect, it won't work). I asked if you still had the rewrite engine commented. If you uncommented that and it's still not working, then I don't know what's wrong, because all your `RewriteRule`/`RewriteCond` is correct

Comment: Yes, I uncommented that and it did not work. It's as though something is overriding it. If " "Redirect 301 /cat_cp.asp?cid=179 amep.com/index.php?route=product/… does not work, what would work. What should it be?

Comment: This is my redirect from old url to new one but with same domain name.`Redirect 301 /old/page /new/page1` . So when is sees the old path it changes to the new one. Hope it helps :)